# How to using select with multi table in SubSonic query?

Tags: subsonic

I am new with SubSonic and have a problem with query. This is my query string

```
string sql = "SELECT *" +
             " FROM tbl_exrates, tbl_currency" +
             " WHERE date = " + d;
             " AND tbl_exrates.currency = tbl_currency.cid" +
             " AND (cash > 0 OR transfer > 0 OR sell > 0)";
```

How to convert it to SubSonic Query string ? Does SS have function support to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q = new Select().From(TblExrate.Schema)
        .InnerJoin(TblCurrency.Schema)
        .Where(tbl_exrates.date).IsEqualTo(d)
        .AndExpression(tbl_exrates.cash).IsGreaterThan(0)
        .Or(tbl_exrates.transfer).IsGreaterThan(0)
        .Or(tbl_exrates.cash).IsGreaterThan(0);
```

Comment: This a great answer, as long as readers remember that SubSonic infers the relationship between TblExrate and TblCurrency based on the existence of a foreign key. I forget what happens if the foreign key doesn't exist--does the query fail?

Comment: I'm sure it will fail, although I don't know how exactly.